# Paradox: No Such Method Exception but Method Appears in Content Assist?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, compilation, bytecode

I had to make a few minor changes to a class using [Recaf](https://github.com/Col-E/Recaf). Part of the change included adding a new constructor with two parameters -> `constructor(File, boolean)` (the old class had only one constructor with a single parameter -> `constructor(File)` ). After making the edit to class using *Recaf* I exported the program (*File -> Export program*) and then re-imported the modified class to the jar file the class was originally part of. I assumed the class would now be updated with the new constructor.

When I type the class name in `Eclipse`, `Content Assist` indeed displays the new constructor that I added. However, when I run the program I get `NoSuchMethod Exception`. Moreover, when open class file via `Open Deceleration` I only see the original (old) constructor there. The new constructor is not there.

*I'm confused*. Was the class actually updated with the new constructor? If yes, why doesn't it appear when I open the class file? If not, why is it showing up in `Content Assist - Autocomplete`?

Assuming it was not updated, how can I force it to be updated?

I refreshed everything in Eclipse and even cleaned and rebuilt project but it didn't help.

Why isn't class being updated to the new version?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your command line that is used to run your application (in the run configuration there is a button _Show Command Line_ for that).

Comment: @howlger thanks for your reply. The command line shown is: C:\app\java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\javaw.exe
-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 seleniumX.SeleniumMain

Comment: In the command line the classpath is missing. Please delete the run configuration and try again. If this does not help, please add the whole command line of the recreated run configuration to your question.